# avoid multiple sticky divs overlapping with each other with CSS only (no javascript)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create something similar to the link below
https://www.msn.com/en-gb/cars/news/this-barn-find-ferrari-just-sold-for-dollar13m/ss-BBMrCrE?li=BBoPWjQ

I have managed to create http://insurethe.000webhostapp.com/template.html so far.

I wanted the text "HEADING SPACE IN PAGE" to always remain on the top and always visible without scrolled away just like the msn search box.

I wanted the Sidebar not to overlap the text "HEADING SPACE IN PAGE" when scrolled.

And finally when I scroll and reach the text "HEADING SPACE IN PAGE must be still visible" I wanted the text "HEADING SPACE IN PAGE" to be still visible.

Also I do not know which CSS styles are needed and not needed to accomplish this task. I wanted to know what all CSS styles I can remove with out impacting the above mentioned behavior.

Comment: Please post the source code next time

Comment: http://insurethe.000webhostapp.com/template.html has the source code. How do I edit the question now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to achieve what i think you are trying to do you just need to make some minor tweaks to your code.

Firstly you need to have the entire html under the same wrapper. So in your html you have two:

```
   <div class="wrapper cf"></div>
```

you need to remove the second one, and make the first one wrap the whole thing. Then you need to give sidebar a css command:

```
    .sidebar {
      top: 110px;
    }
```

Then remove

```
   .wrapper {
       margin-bottom:200px;
   }
```

as this will stop the sidebar overlapping when you get to the bottom of the page.

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/QVEaOp?editors=1100

Let me know if this is now working how you want it to!

edit as per request:

add the second wrapper back in, and give sidebar z-index:-1;

edit 2: just remembered, you will also need to move the header

```
   <div style="position:sticky;top:0;background:white;height:100px;text-align:center;">
      <h1 style="color:orange">HEADING SPACE IN PAGE</h1>
      <strong style="color:red">Sidebar </strong>must be always below this line
      <hr>
   </div>
```

to in between the body tag and the first wrapper. see the codepen for updated code. [you will need to add css to put the width back how you wanted it however]

Comment: Yeah, but now the sidebar always stays on right hand side. The reason I had 2 'wrapper cf' was to achieve scrolling of sidebar again once "HEADING SPACE IN PAGE must be still visible" is reached. So basically, what I am trying to achieve is when I reach the second h1 on the page the sidebar must scroll up. the first h1 must still be always on the top. the sidebar must scroll away under the first h1. Basically like the page below https://www.msn.com/en-gb/cars/news/this-barn-find-ferrari-just-sold-for-dollar13m/ss-BBMrCrE?li=BBoPWjQ

Comment: Thank you. can you please explain what did you do ? Also please let me know what I must do to keep the first h1 still sticky. Now when I scroll further down the sticky h1 is scrolling away.

Comment: sorry refresh it and see again, i forgot to alter something!

Comment: basically the issue was that html layout. Because position: sticky makes it a fixed position within its parent element, the other wrapper was pushing it away because they were separate elements. So by moving the header out of either wrapper, it never gets pushed out the way. With the sidebar, you do want it pushed out the way when the second wrapper comes into view so thats fine. All that was needed then was to 1) make sure the sidebar was layered to be behind the header [z-index] and give the sidebar a location. All position commands support manually altering the elements location.

Comment: with commands such as top:; bottom:; left:; right:; eg: top:0px; left:50px;

Comment: does that all make sense? Also if my answer is the correct solution for you please dont forget to mark it as so. [click the tick under upvote/downvote]

Comment: Yeah. it does. Thank you. Also are the below css needed ? What are the css styles which are not needed to achieve the divs ? html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
If I remove those the stuff does not work as expected.

Comment: keep html { box-sizing: border-box; } *, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; } as that is a css reset / normalise code. It helps ensure your code works the same across all browsers. so if you take that out it may work as expected on say chrome, but not on firefox [for example]